# Can you play Minecraft on a normal Windows 10 fresh from the store

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m getting a windows 10 PC so I’m wondering if I can play java on windows 10 fresh from the store.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

As long as you can download Minecraft: Java Edition from the [official Minecraft website](https://minecraft.net) you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

> I can play java on windows 10 fresh from the store.

There are two stores:

- **Minecraft: Java Edition** from [Minecraft.net](https://www.minecraft.net/)
- **Minecraft** from the [Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/minecraft-for-windows-10/9nblggh2jhxj) (which is cross-platform compatible)

On the website you can download a launcher, login, and download everything you need; Java is automatically downloaded for you without you needed to install it.

If you're using the Windows Store Version you can play it with only downloading assets, as that version doesn't use Java and from what I've heard could preform better on old computers.